# Determination of a uniformly continuous, not locally Hölder-continuous function over an open set

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Given an open interval $I=(a,b)$, I would like to exhibit a uniformly continuous function over $I$ that is not locally Hölder-continuous with exponent $\alpha$ for any $\alpha\in(0,1)$.

It is quite easy to exhibit an UC-function that is not globally Hölder-continuous for a given exponent, or an UC-function that, in a neighbourhood of a single point, is not Holder-continuous for any exponent, but how can we bring this type of "singularity" in any open neighbourhood belonging to $I$?

My first try was to consider UC-functions with "very fast local variation", i.e. nowhere or almost-nowhere differentiable functions, like the [Weierstrass function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function). Unfortunately, the Weierstrass function, despite its weird behaviour, *is* Hölder-continuous.

Comment: In order to help you do your homework (notably different from us doing your homework) it is paramount that you include in your question: 1. Your attempts on the problem; 2. What part of it you're stuck on (see also [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803)). If you [edit] your question to provide this information, it is much more likely that we can help you. Thanks. :)

Comment: Edited in order to meet site policies.

Comment: I would be glad to see the question re-opened; I think that just as now, it perfectly fits the rules - only one vote missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By considering that (thanks to Marco D'Addezio)
$$ f(x)=-\frac{1}{\log x} $$
is not $\alpha$-Holder continuous in a right neighbourhood of zero for any $\alpha\in(0,1)$ (as the inverse of the "really flat" function $\exp(-1/x)$), we can take:
$$ g(x)=\frac{1}{\log 4-\log \sin^2(\pi x)}$$
(defined as $0$ if $x\in\mathbb{Z}$) to have a 1-periodic uniformly continuous function over $\mathbb{R}$, that is not locally Holder-continuous in any neighbourhood of an integer, and is locally Lipschitz-continuous over $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$. By condensation of singularities, i.e. by considering the following sum of translates of $g(x)$ over the dyadic rationals in $(0,1)$ (any countable dense subset can play the same role):
$$h(x)=g(x)+\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{3^j}\sum_{k=1}^{2^{j-1}}g\left(x-\frac{2k-1}{2^j}\right)$$
we still have a periodic uniformly continuous function over $\mathbb{R}$, that is nowhere locally $\alpha$-Holder continuous for any $\alpha\in(0,1)$.